# Phpmyadmin wont let me create new database. Says no privilage

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I'm working on IIS.  I am trying to copy a table or create a new table in phpmyadmin so I can mess around with a database to try and fix some other problems I am having.  However when I try to create a new database it says "No Privilages".  Can someone help me fix this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The person responsible for your MySQL is the one to contact.